# Unobtrusive validation in web forms, not adding data dash tags to form fields

Tags: asp.net, unobtrusive-validation

ASP.NET 4.5 introduced data- tags to web forms apps.

However, they only seem to be added to validation controls (eg required field).

You can see this if you create an "ASP.NET Web Forms Site" and go to the Login page.

In contrast, in an MVC 4+ website, it adds data- tags to the actual form fields. This enables the field to be outlined in red if there is an error.

How can I add these data- tags to form fields in web forms apps?